# Rails shuffle with priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shuffle

I've got a model with some records with an own priority.

1. Record => priority: 1
2. Record => priority: 2
3. Record => priority: 3
4. Record => priority: 3
5. Record => priority: 2
6. Record => priority: 1
7. Record => priority: 1
8. Record => priority: 4

Now I need a random record based on it's priority.
Priority 1 is the worst.
Priority 4 is the best.

Now I get just a random record with `@records.all.shuffle`
What is the best way to combine it with it's priority?

Comment: random record based on something? how is this random then? :)

Comment: For example you got some advert partners. One partner is paying more. So this partner should be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like:

```
max_priority = Record.maximum(:priority)
Record.where(priority: max_priority).all.shuffle
```

Postgresql way:

```
Record.order('priority DESC, RANDOM()').first
```

Comment: That was the correct hint for me. I had a blackout.